# I propose a comment flag tag for "debating troll"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

...or something along those lines. The current comment flag options give us no defense against the trolls to come. I know that comment flags were suggested as a defense, maybe I just need to be informed as to how better to use the current options.

But in any case, I believe that a comment flag **to help avoid debates** in the comment areas is best.

Comment: Are the existing options of  "not-constructive / off-topic" or "too chatty" not sufficient?

Comment: "to help avoid debates" would be the key to this tag.

Answer (score 13):

We already have "rude or offensive" and "not constructive / off-topic" -- those pretty much cover the gamut of troll behavior.

Good flagging practices should address the *content* being flagged, not the *author of the content*.  A comment is good or bad regardless of the person posting it.

Comment: For fun purposes though, I still think 10k+ users should have a troll flag :>